# Prove if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_o)^n$ is conditionally convergent in $x_1$, then $R=|x_1-x_0|$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, conditional-convergence

Prove if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_o)^n$ is  conditionally  convergent at $x_1$, then $R=|x_1-x_0|$ ( $R$ is radius of convergence)

First, According to Abel's Theorem. I know that:

(1) if  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_o)^n$ is convergent at $x_1$, then $R\ge|x_1-x_o|$

(2) if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_o)^n$ is divergent at $x_1$, then $R\le|x_1-x_o|$

Actually my text book says that the question can be proved using (1) and (2). And the hint given by the textbook is method of contradiction. This maybe a stupid question, cause this should be a part of Abel's Theorem. But I want to figure out how does (1) and (2) get my question.

Comment: (2) shows that $R\ge|x_1-x_0|$, right? Seems to me for the rest of it you want a somewhat stronger statement than (1), namely the fact that if $R>|x_1-x_0|$ then the series converges absolutely,

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Actually, I want a stronger staement like you said too. But I can't prove it or find it in my textbook.

Comment: It's in the book somewhere. If not you're reading the wrong book. It's very simple: Say $|x_1-x_0|<R$. Choose $r$ so $|x_1-x_0|<r<R$. By definition of $R$, the series converges when $|x-x_0|=r$. Hence the terms are bounded for $|x-x_0|=r$, and that says the series converges absolutely at $x_1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'll check my textbook clearly tomorrow. Many thanks.